# can't get getDirectory work on android device with phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I my app I use phonegap build to compile it for android. I need to create a persistent folder to store some audio files but I can't make it work... Here is my code :

in config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="0.2.4" />
```

And in my index.html :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//

function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("mynewfolder", {create: true}, gotDir);
        console.log(fileSystem.root);

}

function gotDir(dirEntry) {
        dirEntry.getFile("myfile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: true}, gotFile);
}

function gotFile(fileEntry) {
        // Do something with fileEntry here
}
```

I have no explanation do you have some clues? The console give nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well your code was fine but the problem was you missed error callback.... So your modified code will look like

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//

function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("mynewfolder", {create: true}, gotDir,fail);
        console.log(fileSystem.root);

}

function gotDir(dirEntry) {
        dirEntry.getFile("myfile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: true}, gotFile,fail);
}

function gotFile(fileEntry) {
        // Do something with fileEntry here
}  

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Indeed with the fail function it works!

Comment: executing fileSystem.root.getDirectory cause the fail call and not the gotDir call. Did you know why? console.log(filesystem.root) prints the following line: DirectoryEntry {isFile: false, isDirectory: true, name: = "", fullPath: "/", filesystem: Filesystem, ...}

Comment: This Code-Snipped works for me: http://databasefaq.com/index.php/answer/91977/javascript-ios-cordova-text-files-filewriter-javascript-and-cordova-phonegap-filewriter-gives-invalid-modification-error-on-a-simple-text-file-write but i changed cordova.file.applicationDirectory to cordova.file.externalRootDirectory